# How to know if I am running SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I ran `@@version`.

This is what it gave me:

*Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP2) - 10.0.4000.0 (X64)   Sep 16 2010 19:43:16   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0  (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)*

How do I know if this is r2?

Comment: Your `@@version` output would say so: `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 **R2** (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)`

Answer (score 4):

If you were running SQL Server 2008 R2 it would have `10.5.xxx` instead of `10.0.xxx`.  And it would also say `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 ...`.

You can always find out the named version by the major/minor build number:

- **10.5** : 2008 R2
- **10** : 2008
- **9** : 2005
- **8** : 2000
- ...so on and so forth

Answer (score 3):

Here's a nice comprehensive list of SQL Server version numbers.

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-versions

Comment: I dont get it i try to do an update to r2 but it gives me: [Error Message]
The Instance ID 'MSSQLSERVER' is already in use by SQL Server instance 'MSSQLSERVER.INACTIVE'. To continue, specify a unique Instance ID. 

[Details]
Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingValidationException: The Instance ID 'MSSQLSERVER' is already in use by SQL Server instance 'MSSQLSERVER.INACTIVE'. To continue, specify a unique Instance ID. 
================================================================================

Comment: @oJM86o That's because you are trying to install an instance with the name `MSSQLSERVER`.  That is the default instance which you must already have.  It looks like you are doing an install, instead of an upgrade.  There is a spot in the SQL Server Installation Center for Upgrading in the Installation section.

Comment: @shark that is what I am doing upgrading from 2008 to r2, the setup failed the first time so I am retrying and that is the error I receive....and I do want to upgrade the default instance.

Comment: @oJM86o If the upgrade failed the first time, you may be stuck in some unstable, in-between state now.

Comment: @oJM86o http://manu-sqlserverblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/instance-id-mssqlserver-is-already-in.html Check out that link.  Looks like that might have your solution.

Comment: @shark yea I was performing that after I posted already